# Fullcalendar on Oracle Apex

Tags: fullcalendar, oracle-apex

a client asked me if it is possible to paint a red color to a day cell (apply a css class) if that day contains 7 or more events.

Is it possible through javascript with FullCalendar?

I'm using Oracle APEX 18.1

The idea is something like this screenshot:
[Immagine Esempio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JMns.png)

Answer (score 0):

The cells can be selected in CSS by e.g. `td[data-date="2020-03-18"]`

So on page load in a PL/SQL region you could use SQL to figure out which cells have 7 or more entries, and build some CSS to style them.